# MissingTopicHandler not called for wildcard topic path

Tags: push-diffusion

I have a control client that creates topics on demand (when a client subscribes to a topic that doesn't exist, it is created). I'm using [`MissingTopicHandler`](http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/latest/java/com/pushtechnology/diffusion/client/features/control/topics/TopicControl.MissingTopicHandler.html) to get notification when a client requests a topic that does not exist, and then I create it.

This works fine when my client subscribes to a concrete topic path such as `>myTopic`, but not when a client subscribes to a [wildcard topic path](http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/latest/manual/html/designguide/data/publication/topic_selector_unified.html) such as `?myTopic//`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Strictly speaking "wildcard topic path" are better known to as "topic selectors". [They come in flavours](http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/latest/manual/html/designguide/data/publication/topic_selector_unified.html) including "split path", "full path" and "selector set".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subscribe to a [topic selector](http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/5.7.2/manual/html/designguide/data/publication/topic_selector_unified.html) as opposed to a topic path, the [MissingTopicHandler](http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/5.7.3/java/com/pushtechnology/diffusion/client/features/control/topics/TopicControl.MissingTopicHandler.html) will not be triggered unless the concrete topic that is used in your wildcard topic path is missing.

For your example, if a client subscribes to `?myTopic//`, and the topic `myTopic` exists, no notification is sent. However, if the topic does not exist, then a topic missing notification is sent for this topic (if there is a MissingTopicHandler on this topic path).

For a subscription to a topic selector, there is no missing topic event notification for the children of topic `myTopic`, as there is no attempt to subscribe to an actual topic, but rather a request that when child topics are added below `myTopic` the client is subscribed to them.

**Note**: You cannot get a notification for a subscription to a wildcard topic selector, as there are infinite possibilities matching the selector.